# How to set authorization header coorectly?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

In my react native app in order to remove repeated calls I have developed a general POST GET methods in httpClient file. It code is look likes this.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

var instance = null;

const setAuthorisationHeder = async () => {
  const token = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_data'));
  if (token) {
    console.log('>>>>>> instance', instance);
    Object.assign(instance.headers, {
      Authorization: 'Bearer' + token.accessToken,
    });
  } else {
    console.log('>>>>>> instance', instance);
    Object.assign(instance.headers, {
      Authorization: '',
    });
  }
};

export const setHeader = () => {
  console.log('>>>>>>>> HIIII');
  instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: '',
    timeout: 150000,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
      if (error.response.status) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          AsyncStorage.removeItem('auth_data');
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  );
};

export const Get = (route, data) => {
  function getData() {
    return instance.get(
      route,
      data == null ? {data: {}} : {data: JSON.stringify(data)},
    );
  }
  if (instance) {
    console.log('>>>>>> HIIIIii');
    // setAuthorisationHeder();
    return getData();
  }
  return setHeader().then(getData);
};

export const Post = (route, data) => {
  console.log('>>>>>> route', route);
  function postData() {
    return instance.post(route, JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  if (instance) {
    console.log('>>>>>> HIIIIii');
    // setAuthorisationHeder();
    // setAuthorisationHeder();
    return postData();
  }

  return setHeader().then(postData);
};
```

Can some tell me a way to add an authorization header to this instance? My token is storing the Asyncstorage in the middle of some actions so at the beginning called I don't have the token. As my code setHeader is running only one time so I created a method call setAuthorisationHeder() function. But it is giving me can not find property .then error when I am putting a request. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

`you can define global headers once and use it in every network call.`

https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults

Answer (score 0):

Create a global auth variable where you'll store the auth data from storage. Before making a request get the auth data and use interceptor to set the bearer token.

```
let authToken = '';

const getAuthToken = async () => {
  // asumming auth token was saved as string
  authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_data');
};
```

Interceptor

```
// request interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;

    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

complete code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

let authToken = '';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: '',
  timeout: 150000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

// request interceptor
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${authToken}`;

    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

const getAuthToken = async () => {
  // asumming auth token was saved as string
  authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_data');
};

export const Get = async (route, data = {}) => {
  // get and set auth token
  await getAuthToken();
  // route = /user?id=787878 or /user/787878
  return await axiosInstance.get(route);
};

export const Post = async (route, data = {}) => {
  await getAuthToken();
  return await axiosInstance.post(route, data);
};
```